# How to pass bash variable to JSON

Tags: json, bash, curl, github

I'm trying to write a sample script where I'm generating names like 'student-101...student-160'. I need to post JSON data and when I do, I get a JSON parse error.

Here's my script:

```
name="student-10"

for i in {1..1}
do
    r_name=$name$i
    echo $r_name
    curl -i -H 'Authorization: token <token>' -d '{"name": $r_name, "private": true}' "<URL>" >> create_repos_1.txt
    echo created $r_name
done
```

I always get a `"Problems parsing JSON"` error. I've tried various combination of quotes, etc but nothing seems to work!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note, if you ever start pushing _real_ names this way (from a database, from a web form), then please please [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053678/escaping-characters-in-bash-for-json) them.

Comment: what is the point of using 1-value sequence `{1..1}` ?

Comment: @RuudHelderman That's good advice! I'll keep it in mind

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest oh, just one push at the moment. I'll increase that to 60 later on!

Answer (score 7):

First, your `name` property is a string, so you need to add double quotes to it in your json.

Second, using single quotes, bash won't do variable expansion: it won't replace `$r_name` with the variable content (see [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash-shell-script) for more information).

In summary, use:

```
-d '{"name": "'"$r_name"'", "private": true}'
```

Comment: You now have `$r_name` unquoted, so when the shell expands it, it will be subject to word splitting and pathname expansion. You want `-d '{"name": "'"$r_name"'", "private": true}'`

Comment: this worked for me. However, I couldn't understand the difference between the quotes :(

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `printf` to create the data string:

```
printf -v data '{"name": "%s", "private": true}' "$r_name"
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token <token>' -d "$data" "$url" >> create_repos_1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't; use `jq` (or something similar) to build correctly quoted JSON using variable inputs.

```
name="student-10"

for i in {1..1}
do
    r_name=$name$i
    jq -n --arg r_name "$r_name" '{name: $r_name, private: true}' |
      curl -i -H 'Authorization: token <token>' -d @- "<URL>" >> create_repos_1.txt
    echo created $r_name
done
```

The `@-` argument tells `curl` to read data from standard input (via the pipe from `jq`) to use for `-d`.

---

Something like `"{\"name\": \"$r_name\", \"private\": true}"` may work, but it is ugly and will also fail if `r_name` contains any character which needs to be quoted in the resulting JSON, such as double quotes or ASCII control characters.