# Sanitize a string for json

Tags: bash, posix

I have a very long string that is the output of some commands that I need to send as JSON. It is full of invalid chars and invalid escapes.
Unfortunately, I can't use jq or any other utility that is not automatically installed on mac and Linux.
Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what counts as "automatically installed on Mac and Linux"? I've seen very few general-purpose Linux distros in the last 10 years that don't come with Python, for example, and Python comes with very good JSON libraries.

Comment: ...however, that _general-purpose_ qualifier is important. Linux itself is just a kernel, it doesn't come with _any_ userland software at all, not even a shell; and there are distro-building tools (like Buildroot) that make _everything_ optional, down to the libc. It doesn't make sense to talk about what Linux comes with, without talking about a specific distribution.

Comment: ...if the question is "does POSIX specify anything that includes a JSON generator?", the answer is firmly "no".

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of the question having answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466143/14122 -- even though the accepted answer doesn't work for you, the one directly linked earlier in this comment (presuming Python's availability, which _is_ -- as-discussed -- out-of-the-box on any major general-purpose distro) will.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I meant Mac, Ubuntu and Centos. And I was looking for a pure bash/awk/tr implementation. I can't use tool like jq or other stuff. I think this question it's not a duplicate of the one that @CharlesDuffy pointed out. Anyway, I agree I should be more detailed and specific in my answer.

Comment: MacOS, Ubuntu and CentOS all provide Python, so the answer I linked above will work for you.

Comment: Bash uses C strings, which aren't allowed to contain NULs (as NUL characters terminate them). JSON allows NUL literals, represented as `"\u0000"`. Thus, bash can't even assign all the strings one can represent in JSON to a (regular string) variable in the first place. (Is it possible to work around that? Yes, by using an array to store your string, split into a new element at each NUL and doing special-case handling at the end; but it's so unwieldy as to make code that's hard to write and hard to debug when doing such tricks).

Comment: Part of the above means that if you're assigning the output of a command that spits out binary data to a shell variable, it's liable to have already been corrupted (either deleting NUL characters or truncating at the first one depending on exactly which shell version you're running) _just by trying to store it in that variable in the first place_. By contrast, Python uses "Pascal-style" strings; they can contain NULs, so it can handle arbitrary binary data correctly.