# cat and curl large JSON value from gitlab ci

Tags: json, bash, curl, gitlab, cat

There are many questions on how to post JSON via `curl`. And I am able to send one word as json but not the whole text.

My requirement is to comment a merge request when one job fail in our GitLab CI.

```
# From .gitlab-ci.yaml
  after_script:
    - report=$(find services/ -name '*_latest_failure.md')
    - comment="Job failed.\n\n$(cat "$report")"
    - if [[ "${CI_JOB_STATUS}" == "failed" ]] ; then bash -c "source .gitlab-ci/gitlab.sh; gitlab-comment_merge_request "$comment"" ; fi
```

```
# From .gitlab-ci/gitlab.sh
function gitlab-comment_merge_request() {
  url="https://$CI_SERVER_HOST/api/v4/projects/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID/notes"
  comment="$1"
  curl -v --location -X POST "$url" \
    --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_CI_TOKEN" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{"body": "'"$comment"'"}'
}
```

Unfortunately, the comment that is created contains only the first word, *Job*.

I have tried many techniques to build and send the JSON payload. But all give the same result.

So I thought it could be a mistake when creating the `$comment` variable in my `.gitlab-ci.yaml`. However, `echo $comment` in the same file give the right content.

Now, I'm lost. Do you know why the `$comment` variable that should contain a large text (a markdown text with title, subtitles, and lists) is not sent ?

Thanks

Comment: And when you run `bash -c "...$variable..."`, `$variable` is expanded by the _outer_ shell, not the inner one. That doesn't just mean anything the inner shell does to assign the variable gets discarded (though it _does_ mean that); it also opens you up to injection vulnerabilities. **Always** use a single-quoted context for parameter expansions whose results will be evaluated as code.

Comment: And when you want variables to be visible to subprocesses past an exec boundary, you need to export them into the environment.

Comment: _And_, beyond that, `function funcname() {` merges the POSIX sh syntax `funcname() {` and the historical ksh syntax `function funcname {` in a way that's incompatible with _both_ POSIX sh and legacy ksh.

Comment: And JSON escaping is harder than your code makes it look. Don't try to do it in native bash -- this is what jq is for; _use it_.

Comment: (in particular, newlines need to be replaced with `\n` sequences; your code wasn't doing that, so whenever your markdown files had newlines you were creating invalid JSON... or they would have, if there weren't bugs being hit stopping them from being read at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified version of this would look like:

```
nl='
'
comment="Job failed.${nl}${nl}$(find services/ -name '*_latest_failure.md' -exec cat -- {} +)"
if [ "${CI_JOB_STATUS}" = "failed" ] ; then
  . .gitlab-ci/gitlab.sh
  gitlab_comment_merge_request "$comment"
fi
```

Note:

- Because you were quoting the output from `find` before passing it to `cat`, `cat` was looking for a single file with *all the filenames concatenated together* as its name. Don't do that. Using `find ... -exec cat -- {} +` correctly handles names with spaces without creating new bugs.
- We've taken out bash-only syntax: Changed `==` to `=`, `[[` to `[`.
- We took out the use of `bash -c` and the exec boundary between parent and child processes it implied. If we *hadn't* done this we would need to `export comment`.
- We changed the `source` keyword to its POSIX-compliant synonym, `.`
- We took the dash out of the function name (this does require the file being sourced to change).

A POSIX-compliant version of your function might look like:

```
# note we had to rename this: dashes are not required to work in function names in sh
gitlab_comment_merge_request() {
  url="https://$CI_SERVER_HOST/api/v4/projects/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID/notes"
  body=$(jq -n --var comment "$1" '{"body":$comment}') 
  curl -v --location -X POST "$url" \
    --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_CI_TOKEN" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data "$body"
}
```

If you don't have `jq` installed, it's [straightforward to write a shell wrapper for Python's `json` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466143/14122) for the same purpose.

Comment: Better stream the JSON to curl's STDIN in case JSON payload may be large due to comment: `jq -cn --var comment "$1" '{"body":$comment}' | curl -v --location -X POST "$url" --data @- --other --options...`

Comment: Thanks, Charles. Just note that `comment="$1" is now useless. And I had to use `--arg` instead of `--var` in jq. As suggested by Léa, I piped jq to curl.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to minimize all the logic and JSON formatting into a single shell script:

`gitlab-ci.yaml`:

```yaml
  after_script:
    - bash failed-reports.sh
```

`failed-reports.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# If no failed job do nothing, exit
[ "$CI_JOB_STATUS" = failed ] || exit

# Pass latest_failure files into arguments
set -- ./services/*_latest_failure.md

# If argument 1 is pattern there is no latest_failure to process
[ "$1" = './services/*_latest_failure.md' ] && exit

# Dummy url for demo purpose
url='https://example.com/'

# Prepare report as a stream
{
    printf '# Job failed.\n\n'
    # Iterate each latest_failure from arguments
    for latest_failure; do
        # Skip file if not readabe or non existent
        [ -r "$latest_failure" ] || continue
        # Document name in Markdown bold with blank line
        printf '## Report `%s`:\n\n' "${latest_failure##*/}"
        # Stream latest_failure markdown
        cat "$latest_failure"
        echo # add a newline after streaming report markdown
    done
} |
# Stream to jq to process report as raw input string into JSON
jq \
    --slurp \
    --raw-input \
    --compact-output \
    '{"body": .}' |
# Stream JSON data to curl so that it can handle very large payloads
curl \
    --url "$url" \
    --location \
    --request POST \
    --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_CI_TOKEN" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data @- # This takes data from the STDIN stream
```

In case the JSON data payload is very large, it is a safer option to stream it to curl with `--data @-` rather than passing it as an argument which turns out to be rather limited by the system's maximum allowed argument length.

Comment: Might want to handle the case where the glob expression doesn't match anything at all? Otherwise, this looks very good to me.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy handled now with `[ -r "$latest_failure" ] || continue`

Comment: Thanks. Sure, it is possible to minimize the logic. However, I there are many "scripts" that can comment a merge request. So I prefer to keep the function dedicated for that.